# Jenkins not able to load in local host

Tags: jenkins

After installing `jenkins` i have pasted the auto generated pw from cmd promt after that its not loading.

Its showing below error please check it

```
localhost refused to connect. Search Google for localhost 8090 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Please Check if jenkins is running.
2) Check if you are try to load URL on correct port.(by default can it 8080, if you haven't change)